# Popup with alpha background from current screen in libgdx

Tags: android, performance, libgdx

I want to do a popup screen with some buttons, this screen is small compared to the screen who call this popup.

So, to make it better looking, I think to use an alpha version of the current screen as background of the popup.

I have done "well" with some logic like:

```
...
TextureRegion screenShot = new TextureRegion(ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferTexture());
setScreen(new PopupScreen(this, screenShot));
...
```

And on render() of PopupScreen, I just render the screenShot param.

This works like a charm on desktop version, super fast.

But when I run this on an Android.. the command ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferTexture is very slow  :? (tested on a GS4).

So the question is: I'm doing something wrong or is there any other way to accomplish this?

Thx all

Answer (score 0):

`getFrameBufferTexture` is slow for a couple reasons.  First its reading from the GPU (which is generally much less efficient than writing to a GPU), plus it creates new `Pixmap` and `Texture` objects.  If you look at [the source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ScreenUtils.java#L55) its pretty simple, and you could write a version that reuses `Pixmap` and `Texture`.  But that probably won't help enough to make a big difference.

I think you might have better luck making your pop-up "full screen" but making most of it transparent with the actual content centered in the middle.  Rendering a full-screen semi-transparent image can be a little slow, but since your game is (presumably) paused when the menu is up, it shouldn't matter that its slow.  (I'm also assuming the problem with your existing approach is that it is slow to get started.)

Comment: Thx for your answer.
Yeah.. on android it's take almost 1sec to process getFrameBufferTexture.
I have tried this approach of full screeen transparent, but I was unable to make it work because of the clear commands of the render(): Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
If I remove the clear.. the image got painted over itself every frame :S
Is there a way to clear current screen but leaving last screen behind?

Comment: After clearing the screen, render your game screen and then render the  menu screen (I don't think its worth playing games with not clearing the screen on render).

Comment: Hello @P.T. thanks for your ideas, I have done something like you say: 1) draw world games 2) pause world, and draw an alpha image over all screen, 3) draw the popoup. Don't know if it's the best way, but it works. Regards